# pandas row values to column headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a daraframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2],'id2':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2],'value':['a','b','c','d','a','b','c']})

   id1  id2 value
0    1    1     a
1    1    1     b
2    1    1     c
3    1    1     d
4    2    2     a
5    2    2     b
6    2    2     c
```

I need to transform into this form

```
   id1  id2  a  b  c  d
0    1    1  1  1  1  1
1    2    2  1  1  1  0
```

There can be any number of levels in the value variables for each id ranging from 1 to 10. if the level is not present for that id it should be 0 else 1.

I am using anaconda python 3.5, windows 10

Comment: If `2    1    1     c` is changed to `2    1    1     a` what is output?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I will only have one instance of each value. means, for each id there will be only one 'a'. I only need to check the presence with binary values. Also, Id1 and id2 will be exactly same

Comment: Ok, so first 2 solutions are for you.

Comment: Can you please help me with the situation, in case if i have to get the count. like If 2 1 1 c is changed to 2 1 1 a and I need to get the count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If need output `1` and `0` only for presence of `value`:

You can use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), but then is necessary [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`GroupBy.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html):

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['id1','id2'])['value'])
       .groupby(level=[0,1])
       .max()
       .reset_index()
print (df)
   id1  id2  a  b  c  d
0    1    1  1  1  1  1
1    2    2  1  1  1  0
```

Another solution with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), but then is necesary compare with [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) and convert to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html). Last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['id1','id2', 'value'])
      .size()
      .unstack(fill_value=0)
      .gt(0)
      .astype(int)
      .reset_index()
      .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
   id1  id2  a  b  c  d
0    1    1  1  1  1  1
1    2    2  1  1  1  0
```

---

If need count `value`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   'id2':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   'value':['a','b','a','d','a','b','c']})

print (df)
   id1  id2 value
0    1    1     a
1    1    1     b
2    1    1     a
3    1    1     d
4    2    2     a
5    2    2     b
6    2    2     c

df = df.groupby(['id1','id2', 'value'])
       .size()
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
   id1  id2  a  b  c  d
0    1    1  2  1  0  1
1    2    2  1  1  1  0
```

Or:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['id1','id2'], columns='value', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
      .reset_index()
      .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
   id1  id2  a  b  c  d
0    1    1  2  1  0  1
1    2    2  1  1  1  0
```